# Merge objects with matching properties within array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm a bit stuck merging objects (in this case 'adverts') within an array that have a matching property `advertGroupId`. For the matching properties, I would like to retain the earliest `startDate` and overwrite the `endDate` with the latest. Essentially, grouping the adverts together. (A bonus would be to also group the individual `advertId`'s into an array too, but not essential in this case)

I'm aware of how to merge two objects together (eg. `const newObj = {...obj1, ...obj2}`), but this has me a bit stumped! I can't find any other examples online, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is an example of my problem:

```js
const arrayOfAdverts = [
  {
    advertId: 1234,
    startDate: '2020-03-04',
    endDate: '2020-03-04',
    advertGroupId: 1
  },
  {
    advertId: 1235,
    startDate: '2020-03-05',
    endDate: '2020-03-05',
    advertGroupId: 1
  },
  {
    advertId: 1236,
    startDate: '2020-03-07',
    endDate: '2020-03-07',
    advertGroupId: 1
  },
  {
    advertId: 1237,
    startDate: '2020-03-10',
    endDate: '2020-03-10',
    advertGroupId: 2
  },
  {
    advertId: 1238,
    startDate: '2020-03-11',
    endDate: '2020-03-11',
    advertGroupId: 2
  }
]
```

I'm looking for an end result that would be:

```js
const newArray = [
  {
    advertId: [1234, 1235, 1236],
    startDate: '2020-03-04',
    endDate: '2020-03-07',
    advertGroupId: 1
  },
  {
    advertId: [1237, 1238],
    startDate: '2020-03-10',
    endDate: '2020-03-11',
    advertGroupId: 2
  }
]
```

As I say, grouping the individual ID's isn't a requirement but would be a nice-to-have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the dupe target is only for the grouping part, I've put together an example which fulfills all your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/yek0pdf5/

Comment: @Andreas you, Sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. Exactly what I was looking for!